# Get the values of all children of a XML node in Groovy

Tags: xml, groovy

I have an XML file which looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<groups>
    <group no="1">
        <entry>10</entry>
        <entry>11</entry>
        <entry>12</entry>
    </group>
    <group no="2">
        <entry>30</entry>
        <entry>31</entry>
        <entry>32</entry>
    </group>
</groups>
```

**I need to get all entries as an array from the given group.**

Currently I have the following which gives me all nodes, but I only need the values:

```
def group = "1"                                     
def groups = new XmlParser().parseText(new File(/groups.xml/).text);                                    
def groupEntries = groups.group.find {it.attribute('no') == group}.entry
println groupEntries
```

Prints:

```
[entry[attributes={}; value=[10]], entry[attributes={}; value=[11]], entry[attributes={}; value=[12]]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should give you the required result:

```
List<String> groupEntries = groups.group.find { it.@no == group }.entry*.text()
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: if you say Try you should say it in comments

Comment: @verdesrobert Ahhh, so it's a grammatical objection? Updated answer